# How to set context for .setLayoutManager?

Tags: android-studio

I am calling the .setLayoutManger and I get the error that I am calling the function on a null reference object.

I've tried using getContext() as well as getActivity()

```
    eventRecyclerAdapter = new EventRecyclerAdapter(event_list);

    event_list = new ArrayList<>();
    event_list_view = 
  getActivity().findViewById(R.id.blog_list_view);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    event_list_view.setLayoutManager(new 
   LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    event_list_view.setAdapter(eventRecyclerAdapter);
```

Comment: "I get the error that I am calling the function on a null reference object." – That has nothing to do with the `Context` used in instantiating the `LayoutManager`. It means that `event_list_view` is null, which means that `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.blog_list_view);` is returning null. That's not unexpected if the `<RecyclerView>` is in the `Fragment`'s layout. You need to find it in the `Fragment`'s `View`, not in the `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using RecyclerView

This works fine for me :

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());

mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(YourList, getApplicationContext());

mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

I hope this help